# Having Issue on Setting Full Width / Height Caption in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not able to set full carousel size height and width for the `.carousel-caption`? I made this [demo](http://www.bootply.com/9MhfIYNkw9). As you can see I have tried this:

```
.carousel-caption{
     background: rgba(44, 44, 23, 0.2);
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
}
```

but it is not generating a full width/height caption div!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel-caption has a position absolute. Hence try this.

```
.carousel-caption{
    background-color: rgba(44, 44, 23, 0.2);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```